# How do I send notifications on an AndroidTV?

Tags: notifications, android-tv

I have been reading the documentation pages for Notifications for Android devices but I want to build and display notifications on an Android-TV. I have used several apps in the AndroidTV and none of them shows notifications, instead sometimes they appear in the recommendations bar,which leads me to believe that it may not be possible to display notifications on this family of devices.
My end goal is to dispatch a Heads-up notification ([priority flag](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html#correctly_set_and_manage_notification_priority) set to `MAX`) so it can be shown regardless of what the user is doing.

Can someone help me to achieve this, maybe pointing me to some more specific docs?

**UPDATE** I have found [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.cyberdream.androidtv.notifications.google) application that displays notifications, but I cannot understand how it works. Is it possible that it is mimicking notifications without working with Android's API?

Comment: according to [this](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html#correctly_set_and_manage_notification_priority) link, it's a `MAX` priority level type of notification, or Heads-up Notifications as it is apparently called. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, Link is dead

Answer (score 0):

I also think notification will appear as "recommendation" and not appear as "notification".

For the [Notifications for Android TV](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.cyberdream.androidtv.notifications.google) app, I guess it is using [custom designed Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView) instead of Notification.

Comment: Good guess, there is a way to add recommendations in AndroidTV. However, customized Toasts were not really what I was going for because I would like to add buttons to the notification/toast. I am slowly progressing in implementing this using `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`.

Comment: I see. I feel many developers want these features, and it is a loss that Android TV platform does not offer any official functionality about notification (interrupt to user) now.

Comment: I agree. It's a matter of waiting to see if Marshmallow will bring new tools for the platform.